# Passing value from dialog to main window in Qt

Tags: qt

I am using QCreator in Qt5. I have lineEdit_1 in MainWindow and lineEdit_2 in Dialog. When the user enters a value in lineEdit_1, that value should be automatically inserted in lineEdit_2. In order to do that, I have implemented the follows which is still giving me an error:

```
void Dialog::on_lineEdit_editingFinished()
{
    MainWindow main;
    ui->lineEdit->addItem(main->lineEdit->text());
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can try and use this example: http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/QLineEditTextChanged.php This has an event handler for textChanged, but something similar to what you might be trying.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things wrong with your code:

- `QLinedEdit` doesn't have an `addItem(QString)` method. It has a `setText(QString)`.
- you create a `MainWindow` on the stack, this surely isn't right. You need to reference your original main window, not create a new one. You can access the original widget pointer if you parent the dialog to it when you create it, and cast the parent pointer to `MainWindow *` using `qobejct_cast()`.
- you use pointer syntax, but `MainWindow main;` is not a pointer but an instance.
- you are setting an event handler for when the content of the dialog line edit is changed, which is the opposite of what you say you want to do, since you say you want changes in the main ui line edit to be reflected by the dialog line edit.

Comment: I tried the following but with no success. I am extremely confused as to where I am going wrong.

`void Dialog::on_lineEdit_editingFinished()
{
    MainWindow *main;
    ui->lineEdit->setText(main->lineEdit->text());
}`

I am even trying the following but with no success:

`void Dialog::on_lineEdit_editingFinished()
{
    MainWindow *main;
    connect(ui->lineEdit,&QLineEdit::editingFinished,this,&QComboBoxPrivate::addItem);
}
`

Comment: You are using an uninitialized pointer. This won't work, as it doesn't point to anything. Try `MainWindow * main = qobject_cast<MainWindow *>(parent());` and check whether the pointer is not null before using it. Don't forget to set parent the dialog to the main window on its creation. That connection you are trying to make makes no sense.